# redis save option per database - possible?

Tags: save, jedis

I find save option in conf for all the databases. Is it possible to assign different save values per database say 1, 2 , etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. We've to have have another redis instance which can be set with different save values.